# R: How to match strings of variable length in dataframe columns with different row numbers?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have two data frames in R with different number of rows. df1 has 2 columns with 12000+ rows and df2 has <200 rows. Both the data frames have strings as observations. Sample from df1:

```
Name = c("7PR SRO.","7PR","3XL INC","ACME INC","ACME INCORP")
abbr = c("7PR","7PR","3XL","ACME","ACME")
df1<- data.frame(Name, abbr, stringAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The second data frame df2 has same name column as df 1. It only had the name column but to match row entries, i merged them with df1 using the merge function. But i still ended up with around 100+ rows with NA in abbr column. Example:

`df2<- data.frame(Name = c("7PR S.R.O.", "3XL LLC", "ACME Ltd"), stringAsFactors=FALSE)`

df2's name column also has similar company names like df1 but there could be changes in punctuation or changes from "Corp" to "Ltd" etc. Basically I want 3XL as abbr regardless of whether its LLC or Ltd after the name. I tried using stringdist function 
`stringdist(df2$Name,df1$Name,method ='jw')`
but it gives an error saying "Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

What i need to get is `df1$Name` is matched with `df2$Name` ignoring punctuation or changes in company type such as corp, inc, ltd, llc etc. Can someone please help me find a way to do this?

Comment: Share data as *reproducible* R objects not images.

Comment: Hopefully the changes help

Comment: Summarizing, you want to remove all 'INC, INCORP' right? What do you mean by match? Do you want to combine these two dfs? We can do something like: `df2$Name <- gsub( " .*$", "", df2$Name)` to remove all of these stuff and leave only company abbre and then combine the two dfs: `df3 <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by='Name', all = TRUE)`

Comment: @Adamm 1). Yes. removing all 'INC' etc is one part. 2). By match i mean i want to match the column `df2$Name` to `df1$Name` and accordingly match the correct abbr. df1 is a master df from which records are to be matched to avoid double entry. 3). i want to add to df1 with only unique entries from df2. 4)  df2 is not the same as df1. For eg. ACME Inc might be in df2 as ACME LLC or A.C.M.E or ACME industrial Corp. But i want to be find a way to ignore the punctuations etc

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new abbr column for future matching/ merging in df2 seems to be ok for you, so this is what I would do:

1. create a new column df2$abbr in df2 with company names without punctuation
2. using df1$Name as a lookup to extract the abbreviations of company names

```
# adding a multiple-word company name
Name = c("7PR SRO.","7PR","3XL INC","ACME INC","ACME INCORP", "ABC Industrial complex LTD")
abbr = c("7PR","7PR","3XL","ACME","ACME", "ABC Industrial complex")

# make data frames
df1<- data.frame(Name, abbr, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2<- data.frame(Name = c("7PR S.R.O.", "3XL LLC", "A.C.M_E Ltd"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # added some punctation to ACME

# package needed
library(stringr)

# create new column abbr containing the abbreviations
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(abbr = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Name), # get rid of punctuation
         abbr = str_extract(abbr, paste(df1$abbr, collapse = "|"))) # use df1$abbr as lookup
```

Comment: I am not looking to just merge the dfs. I am trying match strings in one master df (df1) to entries in df2 and then  automatically get abbr from the df1, if the entry exists in df1. Please read the comment above for more details.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry... Could you maybe post a desired output?

Comment: Basically if the `df2$name` contains `c("ACME Ltd", A.C.M.E","ACME. Inc")` etc, it would still match the company name to ACME in `df1$abbr` . My desired output would be ACME. Hope that helps.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this helps - if it's still not what you want I will delete my answer. Good luck with finding a solution!

Comment: It works for company names with one word followed by company suffix eg ABC LTD. thanks. But for multiple word names like 'ABC Industrial complex LTD', i only get 'ABC'.  I need the answer to be - 'ABC Industrial Complex'. Is it possible to edit the script above to work on company names like ABC Industrial Complex LTD along with smaller strings such ACME Ltd?

Comment: Something like this?